# Add gradient in datagrid programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've been searching in the internet on how to put gradient in a datagrid programatically but unfortunately I cannot find a good source for this question. How do you do this in a c# code exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick googling gave me below solution from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754083(v=vs.110).aspx#Linear%20Gradients). 
It has an object of LinearGradientBrush class and which is then applied to data grid background. Pretty easy and clean!! You can change StartPoint and EndPoint of the gradient as per your need. Same is explained on MSDN link very well.

```
LinearGradientBrush myLinearGradientBrush =
new LinearGradientBrush();
myLinearGradientBrush.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
myLinearGradientBrush.EndPoint = new Point(1, 1);
myLinearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(
new GradientStop(Colors.Yellow, 0.0));
myLinearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(
new GradientStop(Colors.Red, 0.25));
myLinearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(
new GradientStop(Colors.Blue, 0.75));
myLinearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(
new GradientStop(Colors.LimeGreen, 1.0));

// Use the brush to paint the datagrid .
dg.Background = myLinearGradientBrush; //dg is my datagrid name.
```